# How to make the second group in a regex match before the first

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex in php.

The first group or parenthesized sub pattern is to select an optional date from the beginning of the string.

The last group is supposed to get another optional date from the end of the string. And the `(.+)` in the middle is supposed to get whatever is left in the string. The middle part does not work unless there is a date at the start or end of the string.

How can I make it work even if there is no date at the start or end of the string? The third group needs to match first and let the second match whatever is left. Thanks.

Here is what i have so far, `preg_match("/(^\d{1,2}[\/.]\d{1,2}[\/.]\d{1,4}\b)?(.+)(\b\d{1,2}[\/.]\d{1,2}[\/.]\d{1,4}$)/", $string, $match);`

For example, I would like `(.+)` to get `My text here 55` out of `1/5/18 My text here 55 5.6.2016` and `1/5/18 My text here 55` and `My text here 55`.

Comment: show examples of string and what result do you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly

```
^(\d{1,2}[\/.]\d{1,2}[\/.]\d{1,4}\b)?(.+?)(\b\d{1,2}[\/.]\d{1,2}[\/.]\d{1,4})?$
```

should work for you.

Matches any text that can be surrounded dates

> 11/11/11 text 12/12/12
>
> 11/11/11 text
>
> text 12/12/12

https://regex101.com/r/frkGiH/1/tests